# Relay Outgoing Emails Based On Sender Address AND Recipient domain

Tags: postfix

I am new with postfix and have troubles figuring out some things. Right now my postfix has sender-based config:

```
ajax@mydomain.com send.mydomain2ajax.com:25
foo@mydomain.com send.mydomain2foo.com:25
bar@mydomain.com send.mydomain2bar.com:25
```

Now i also need it to route specific recipient domain to a specific transport, for example:

From: ajax@mydomain.com
To: foo@**outlook**.com should go to 10.0.0.1

From: ajax@mydomain.com
To: foo@**gmail**.com should go to 10.0.0.2

etc.

Is there any way to relay outgoing emails based on both sender address and recipient domain? Thanks in advance!

**edit**: For now the only solution i came up with - is to make my service to send mail from new sender, and then do the same thing, for example:

```
ajax@mydomain.com send.mydomain2ajax.com:25
foo@mydomain.com send.mydomain2foo.com:25
bar@mydomain.com send.mydomain2bar.com:25
ajax_outlook@mydomain.com send2outlook.mydomain2ajax.com:25
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new file:

/etc/postfix/relay_by_sender

then add:

```
test@test.com          smtp:[smtp.test.lan]:587
@example.net           smtp:192.168.1.10:25
no-relay@localhost     smtp
```

run the following command:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/relay_by_sender  
postconf -e "sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_by_sender" 
systemctl restart postfix
```

Comment: This answers half of the question, because you didn't explained how do it for domains. You only answered for a specific sender so this is not an answer